# What voice to use when speaking?

Tags: vocal-range, voice-change

OK, I believe I'm the first one asking this question because I tried to find answer everywhere and just couldn't!

I am 15 years old (almost 16 years old). I always knew how to sing, and two years ago, I joined a choir in my city. After they checked my range they put me as a "young tenor".

Time has passed, and I really don't know if my voice has changed yet, but now I have something really confusing. Right now, this is the situation: my chest voice sounds really low and dark, like a low bass, and that worries me because I want to stay a tenor, as my chest voice can  go down to E2 at its lowest and up to E4 maximum.

The weird thing is, my head voice, which I'm not so sure is a head voice and not a chest voice, can go down to to F2 with much diffuculty and maximum up to F6 with falsetto, but  regularly my head voice is like a natural lyric tenor, just like Bruno Mars, and ***when I speak, I don't know which voice I should use***, the really low one, which some can say might be my chest voice, or the one I regularly use which is my lyric tenor voice.

Please help!!!

Comment: At your age, things haven't completely settled down yet. Why not use the voice/voices that you like best, and take no notice. You must ask your choirmaster as well.

Comment: @Tim Asking the choirmaster which voice OP should *speak* in? Why?

Comment: @user45266 - somewhat naiive! Ask the choirmaster which voice to *sing* in!

Answer (score 1):

Your speaking voice should be what you are comfortable using, both physically as well as in communication.  Your singing voice, again, should be what you are confortable using, both physically as well as matching the music.

You are constraining yourself if you don't allow yourself to adapt to the situation.  You can use a different voice in different situations (I remember that I kept a much lighter/younger voice when distributing magazines and cashing for them: I think I felt that it was better for tips).  You can sing, even the same pitch, in a number of different colors depending on the situation.

Try to maintain all you can into adulthood as long as you are not straining your voice.  You'll never know when you might want to make use of the choices you got.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method is placing your type in the middle of your own range, so you have much space for going low and high when you are singing. Sometimes we can't catch the feeling when singing in a low voice, but there is some technique to resolve that problem: you forget about "singing" first, all you have to do is make a "speech" from the lyrics you are trying to sing in your uncomfortable range. Try to find a "reading style" with your new range until your whole diaphragm identifies a new character. Try to sing like making a dialogue for the first. Don't use any vibration or any vocal technique; then you will find your comfort zone itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand what your saying but my question  is in what voice should I do it, I got used all my life for some reason to speak in some kind of mixed voice and sing in this voice as well, the problem is that this voice sounds really childish, and I don't know what to do about it, in which voice should I speak and do you have any idea what type of voice can I have

Comment: I think it's depend on your vision,,,,,sometimes we busy to do something and forget it's about what, or what value do we expect..focus is number one on everything...about your voice character, I believe is made naturally, everybody has a natural character itself. About how to sing, maybe we have to choose between being ourself.....or made a new character for some reason, maybe for a "good value" or maybe for fit in some songs do we sing. I see Singing is not different like an Actor trying to act to have a good Value on the Story.

Comment: Yes I understand but still I would really like to finally get an answer for the question that I'm asking everywhere for over 3 months, it's driving me crazy cause I don't know if my voice will change anymore, and if he has already changed, and if I'm a bass or a baritone or a tenor, I just really wanna know 